# How do I take the result generated by a button and compare it to another result generated inside another button in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, single-page-application

I have an app where I generate a number with a button, and I want to take the result from here and verify if it's the same with the result generated from the second button when I press it.[image: the code is here]

[image: Here is the interface]

Comment: Please include code, not images of code, which can't be copied/pasted, searched, or read by screen readers. Also, this doesn't appear to have anything to do with `SwiftUI` or `single-page-application`, which you've chosen as tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use variables in class outside the functions.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

   IBOutlet weak var minValueTxt: UITextField!
   IBOutlet weak var maxValueTxt: UITextField!
   //IBOutlet 3
   //IBOutlet 4

   var minNumber: Int = 0
   var maxNumber: Int = 0
   var appNumber: Int = 0

   @IBAction func generateNumber() {
      minNumber = Int(minValueTxt.text!)!
      maxNumber = Int(maxValueTxt.text!)!
      appNumber = Int.random(in:minNumber...maxNumber)
   }

//the rest of the code
}
```